# How can we apply Newtons laws, or kinematics to solve a problem like this one?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

Problem: Two objects with masses 5.00 kg and 2.00 kg hang .600 m above the floor from the ends of a cord 6.00 m long passing over a frictionless pulley. Both objects start from rest. Find the maximum height reached by the 2.00 kg object.

Answer: 1.46 m above the floor

Note: the concept of conservation of energy has not yet been introduced at this point, and can not be a part of the solution. All that can be used are Newtons laws, and Kinematics (when applicable).

Question: How can this be solved using the concepts listed above? My original assumption was that the answer would be 1.2 meters above the ground. Since, the 5.00 kg block only can fall .6 meters before hitting the ground, and when this happens the small block would stop moving. This is clearly false. This means that the small block must have a nonzero force acting upward when this happens ( I believe it's tension). How would I go about calculating this force, or do I even need this force to solve this?

Please let me known if I need to edit any of this to be more concise.

Comment: The arrangement is know as an "Atwood's machine", and it is a basic problem in more-that-one-body mechanics. The important physical fact is that the weights are connected which a rope which is idealized as being flexible but inextensible (it doesn't stretch).

Comment: I didn't put this above, but I assumed this. This means that the only 3 forces that are acting in this system are both the weights and the tension ( that of course affects both boxes equally.) I just don't see how this helps me determine the max height of the box.

Comment: So visualize it. You knock the braces out, the 5 kg side heads down and eventually hits the floor. In the mean time, what is happening to the other side (a) while the 5 kg side is still descending and (b) after the heavy weight hits the floor.

Comment: It is clear that the after the heavy weight hits the floor the small one has an upward velocity. The question is how can I calculate such a velocity to find the end position?

Comment: In any of the usual ways. From the acceleration and distance. Or by conservation of energy.

Comment: I actually solved it using conservation of energy and submitted it online. I'm just still curious as to how I could have done this problem without it. I honestly am lost on how to do this otherwise. By the way, thank you for your super fast reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Straight Newton's Laws plus kinematics solution

An Atwood's machine develops an acceleration of 
$$\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{m_2 - m_1}{m_2 + m_1} g \,,
\end{align*}$$
in the direction of the heavy mass (here $m_2$).

Both objects have this acceleration though in opposite directions, and (assuming the rising one doesn't hit the pulley) it persists over a distance equal to the original height or the heavy mass.

When the heavy mass hits the ground, the light one has a height of $y_0 = 1.200\,\mathrm{m}$ (from the original height and the distance the heavy one has to fall) and a velocity of
$$\begin{align*}
v_0 &= \sqrt{2 a \Delta x} \\
&= \sqrt{2\frac{m_2-m_1}{m_2+m_1}g\Delta x}\,,
\end{align*}$$
(from the kinematics of constant acceleration) with $\Delta x = 0.600\,\mathrm{m}$ the distance available for the heavy mass to fall.

From there is will fly upward as a projectile until reaching a maximum height of
$$\begin{align*}
y &= y_0 + \frac{-v_0^2}{2(-g)} \\
&= y_0 + \frac{m_2 - m_1}{m_2 + m_1} \Delta x\\
&= (1.200\,\mathrm{m}) + \frac{3}{7}(0.600\,\mathrm{m})\\
&= 1.457\,\mathrm{m}\\
&\approx 1.46\,\mathrm{m} \,.
\end{align*}$$

I rather like the way the dependence on $g$ drops out of the expression: it would do the same thing, only slower, on the moon. We can even write $y_0 = 2\Delta x$ leading to $y = \frac{17}{7} \Delta x$.